# Google App engine Not allow thrid party API calling

Tags: google-app-engine

I successfully deployed my project to Google App Engine, and it is working fine. When I'm trying to call some third-party API in our GET/POST method, they will not allow me to call it, and they return the error which is java.net.UnknownHostException. but sometine they call it but most of them they return the error so I was thinking maybe there are some errors in third party API calling. but it's working fine on my local server.

Comment: Please post the code of your API call.

Comment: Api2PdfClient a2pClient = new Api2PdfClient("<API KEY>");
  Api2PdfResponse pdfResponse = a2pClient.libreofficeConvert("https://storage.googleapis.com/staging.cybernetic-day-252520.appspot.com/WordToPdf", false, "test2.pdf");
  
  response.getWriter().append("Served at: "+pdfResponse.getPdf()).append(request.getContextPath());

Comment: Can you specify the full error message? E.g. *"java.net.UnknownHostException: <error message>"*

Comment: Yes @DenisT. here is full error:   java.net.UnknownHostException: v2018.api2pdf.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the Java 8 runtime, the default value is native, which means that standard Java network classes use the standard Java HTTP(S) transport, as described in Java 8 runtime vs Java 7 behavior. This setting requires the app to have billing enabled, otherwise the following runtime errors will result from requests:

```
java.net.UnknownHostException
java.net.SocketTimeoutException
java.io.IOException
```